# Fully convolutional autoencoder for variable-sized images in keras

Tags: deep-learning, convolution, keras, autoencoder

I want to build a convolutional autoencoder where the size of the input in not constant. I'm doing that by stacking up conv-pool layers until I reach an encoding layer, and then doing the reverse with upsample-conv layers. the problem is that no matter what settings I use, I can't get the exact same size in the output layer as the input layer. The reason for that is that the UpSampling layer (given say (2,2) size), doubles the size of the input, so I can't get odd dimensions for instance. Is there a way to tie the output dimension of a given layer to the input dimension of a previous layer for individual samples (as I said, the input size for the max-pool layer in variable)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is.

You can use three methods

- [Padding](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/pad)
- [Resizing](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/resize)
- [Crop or Pad](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/resize_with_crop_or_pad)

Padding will only work to increase the dimensions. Not beneficial for reducing the size.

Resizing should be more costly but optimum solution for each case (up or downsampling). It will keep all the values in the range and will simply resample them to resize in a given dimension.

Crop or Pad will work as resize and it will be more compute-efficient as there is no interpolation in this method. However, if you want to resize it to a smaller dimension, it will crop from the edges.

By using those 3, you can arrange your layer's dimensions.